# Using copy with long file name

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I see that there are different related questions (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224880/batch-file-copy-files-with-certain-extensions-from-multiple-directories-into-one) or [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753420/how-to-copy-specific-file-types-from-one-folder-into-another-folder)), 
but none seems to deal with my problem. 
I am trying to copy all the PDF files that I have in `subfolder` into the current folder.

The following command works well if I put the .bat file and `subfolder` on the  Desktop:

```
for /R "%cd%\subfolder" %%f in (*.pdf) do copy %%f ".\"
```

However, if I put the subfolder and the .bat file in a position characterized by longer path, the script doesn't work anymore.
The path has spaces and underscores, no special characters.

Any help would be highly apppreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the path can have a space in it, then it must be quoted. Since all paths -could- contain a space character, always use quotes.

```
for /R "%cd%\subfolder" %%f in (*.pdf) do copy "%%~f" ".\"
```

Edit: Used "%%~f" as suggested by @aschipfl.